# How is ElasticSearch supposed to work in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, elasticsearch

I've been trying my very best not to ask any nosy question here in stackoverflow, but it has been almost one week since I got stuck in this problem and I couldn't find any solution.

I already have my working website built with CakePHP 3.2. What the website basically does is scrape Twitter for tweets containing a given search term, check if it's already in my database, and store it if it doesn't yet exist. Twitter's JSON response has this "tweet_id" property, and I've been using that value to check for whether I should ignore or append a specific tweet to my DB. While this might be okay while my database is small, I suspect it's going to slow things down considerably when my tables grow bigger. Thus my need for ElasticSearch.

My ElasticSearch server is running on my Arch Linux install, and I've configured my app to point to the said server. Also, I have my "Type" object named the same way as my "Tweets" table (I followed the documentation until the overview part http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html). This craps out an "Unknown method "alias" error, and following Google searches led me to creating an alternate pagination class since that was what some found to be the cause of the error (https://github.com/lorenzo/audit-stash/issues/4), which still doesn't fix things.

I'm not sure if I got this right. I installed the ElasticSearch plugin with the assumption that all I have to do is name the Types the same name as my tables, since to me the documentation "implies" that this should be done on top of the Blog Tutorial they did to "improve query performance".

TLDR, how is this supposed to work? Is my above assumption right? Do I name the Types differently and index everything myself? I'm not sure if there's just too much automagic, or I'm just poor at these sort of things. And yes, I'm new to frameworks (but not PHP, among other languages)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Comment: I'm running ElasticSearch 2.3.2, as told by pointing my browser to localhost:9200. It also says there that my cluster name is "elasticsearch". To be sure, I used that name as the "index" in my app.php ( 'index' => 'elasticsearch' for my elastic datasource.

Comment: `elasticsearch` is the default cluster name, but it has nothing to do with the index name. You should probably name your app index differently.

Comment: I had it named "tweet_id_index" before I started getting desperate to fix this XD I changed it back now